# setting public class property in Yii framework

Tags: php, oop, yii

In the controller (which is a class called MessageController), there is this code, which renders a "view" file named helloWorld and also sets an array where the variable $theTime is connected to the key 'time'.

```
$theTime = date("D M j G:i:s T Y"); 
$this->render('helloWorld',array('time'=>$theTime));
```

In the view helloWorld file, the key 'time' from the controller  is displayed here through the variable $time

```
<h3><?php echo $time; ?></h3>
```

this works perfectly. However, the book also suggests trying another way. It says

> Alter the previous example by defining
>   a public class property on
>   MessageController, rather than a
>   locally scoped variable, whose value
>   is the current date and time. Then
>   display the time in the view file by
>   accessing this class property through
>   $this.

I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. Anyone know how

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class MessageController {
  public $time;

  public function beforeAction($action) {
    $this->time = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
    return true;
  }

  public function someAction() {
    $this->render('helloWorld');
```

in the view:

```
echo $this->time;
```

Comment: I didn't think you could have an expression evaluate to a variable like that, but I tried as you suggested, andI got this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting ',' or ';' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/demo/protected/controllers/MessageController.php on line 6

Comment: I messed up with the code there and edited now. Did not code in `Yii` for a loooong time. I think you better put `$this->time = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");` in `beforeAction($action)` method.

Comment: @Nemoden this (the way you posted it first) is not Yii-specific, you can not assign default value to a property, if it is not a scalar. [See more on properties in PHP 5](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). But now it is ok, if `beforeAction()` is executed.

Comment: @Tadeck, As I said: I messed up with the code. I know that ;) I'm just switching from `Python` to `PHP` and backwise a lot now, so it's a `Pythonical` thing slipped into my `PHP` code. And I did not mean that's `Yii`'s feature.

Comment: @Nemoden Ok, I understand. I am in the similar situation (switching Py & PHP) ;)

Comment: @Tadeck @Nemoden  thanks, this answer works, but I don't think it was the answer the book was looking for because beforeAction hadn't been introduced

Comment: also where does the parameter $action come from?

Comment: @Michael `Yii` passes `CAction` to `beforeAction` by itsself, so you can attach or disable behaviours, set or unset events, tell which action is it ( `getId()` ), etc. see [CAction API reference](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CAction)

Comment: @Michael "I don't think it was the answer the book was looking for". I don't think either :) I read only `Yii`'s blog guide 3 years ago and since then I just read what they did in new revisions and check out things I'm interested in. There are a lot of thing in `Yii` you can do in different ways. I think, my solution is still good.

Answer (score 0):

```
   // I defined $MyClassTime as a public class variable in "MessageController.php" 
    //as follows:

    class MessageController extends Controller
    {
        public $MyClassTime;

        public function actionHelloWorld()
        {
            $this->MyClassTime = "From Public Class Property: " . date("D M j G:i:s T Y");      

            $this->render('helloWorld');

        }

        public function actionIndex()
        {
            $this->render('index');
        }

    // And then did this in "helloWorld.com":

        <?php
        $this->breadcrumbs=array(
            'Message'=>array('message/index'),
            'HelloWorld',
        );?>
        <h1>Hello, World!!</h1> 
        <h3><?php echo $this->MyClassTime; ?></h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

In controllers/MessageController.php file

```
    class MessageController extends Controller
    {
       public $theTime;

       public function init()
       {
           $this->theTime = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
       }

       public function actionHelloWorld()
       {
           $this->render('helloWorld',array('time'=>$this->theTime));
       }
     }
```

In views/message/helloWorld.php

```
    <h3><?php echo $time; ?></h3><hr/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the instruction in the book specifically reads: "Alter the previous example by defining a public class property on MessageController... ...then display the time in the view file by accessing this class property via $this.

That being said, this is what I came up with:

In MessageController.php:

```
            class MessageController extends Controller
            {
                public $defaultAction = 'hello';
                public $theTime; // as per book's instructions

                public function actionHello()
                {
                    $this->theTime = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");
                    $this->render('hello');
                }
```

In protected/views/message/hello.php:

```
            <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
            <h3>
            <?php echo $this->theTime; ?>
            </h3>
```

It works for me, and I understand what is going on in the code. Being a newbie, that is important: to know what you're doing and to implement it.